# How to build the Android .so file using ndk-build.cmd

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine

Getting DllNotFoundException when trying to build a native c++ plugin for Unity.

FirstDll.cpp

```
#include "FirstDll.h"                                                                                                                                                                

  DLLExport int add(int a, int b){
      return a+b;
  }

  FirstDll::FirstDll(){
  }

   FirstDll::~FirstDll(){
 }
```

FirstDll.h

```
#define DLLExport __declspec(dllexport)                                                                                                                                              

   extern "C"{
       DLLExport int add(int a, int b);
   }

  class FirstDll{
  public:
       FirstDll();
      ~FirstDll();
 };
```

I am then generating a so file via this command

```
g++ -dynamiclib -flat_namespace -fms-extensions FirstDll.cpp -o libmyclass.so
```

I am then added this .so file in Assets/Plugins/x86_64 folder and in my unity c# code, I am trying to run this piece of code.

```
[DllImport("myclass")]
    static extern int add(int a, int b);
```

After getting this error, I have tried to moved the so file to different locations and test. I am always getting DllNotFoundException.

```
Found that the DllNotFoundException was coming bcoz the .so file 
is not build using ndk-build.cmd. 
Plz help me with the steps to build the .so file for android.
```

Comment: Are you building for an x86 device/emulator? Can the `.so` file be used directly by an "ordinary" android application (`System.loadLibrary`)? You are probably missing `-fPIC` and [other ABI/arch flags](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis). The correct way to build native android libraries is via NDK, CMake and [add_library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake). The NDK then takes care of using the correct compiler for the various architectures and passing the right ABI flags.

Answer (score 0):

The [NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code) contains instructions about how to [build libraries for Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake). Android Studio is not strictly required for this, but makes it easier. If you don't use it, you have to [install NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) manually.